# Bootstraping with vue 2, router and vue-loader

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-loader

With vuejs 1 the code was:

```
const App = Vue.extend(Index);
router.start(App, '#app');
```

Where `Index` is a component.

I try to convert it to vue 2 like this:

```
const App = Vue.extend(Index);
const app = new App(router).$mount('#app');
```

But this gives an `[Vue warn]: Error when rendering root instance`.

What is the correct way to re-write this?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the router as a parameter:

```
const app = new App({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

Example:

```js
const Index = {
  template: `<div id="app">It's working!</div>`
}
const App = Vue.extend(Index)
const router = new VueRouter()

const app = new App({ router }).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the working code snippet! Now, in my app, it says `Unknown custom element: <router-view>`. Trying to figure out why…

Comment: If you're using npm and webpack/browserify, you have to call `Vue.use(VueRouter)` to make sure that vue-router register the component `<router-view>` @francoisromain

Answer (score 2):

Try this (App == Index)

```
const App = Vue.extend(require('./App.vue'))

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'abstract'
})

new App({
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```